# jQuery Mobile trigger refresh on page (phonegap)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 in a Phonegap app.

I am trying to trigger a reload of the current page I am using. The user deletes something in one part of the page and it effects another part of the page. Hence, the reload.

I have come across a couple of suggestions but nothing so far is working out.

```
$.mobile.changePage( '#shopping-list', { allowSamePageTranstion: true, reloadPage: true, transition:"none" });
```

The above code will not work because they are not seperate HTML pages so reloadPage does not execute. I need to push the page back through 'pageshow'.

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: You could bind to the `pageshow` event and call `.trigger('create')` on the pseudo-page on which the `pageshow` event fired. I'd recommend looking back over the questions you've asked and accept the proper answers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reload the page, you may try to use:

```
$(location).attr('href',"your_html.html");
```

(where `your_html` is the HTML file containing your page `#shopping-list`) instead of:

```
$.mobile.changePage( '#shopping-list', { allowSamePageTranstion: true, reloadPage: true,transition:"none" });
```

However, if you use this solution, I suggest that you only have one page in the HTML file `your_html`, that is: `#shopping-list`.

Hope this will help for you.

You can ask me question.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back. I don't know whether it was a typo on my behalf, but the following code worked for me:`code`     $.mobile.changePage('#shopping-list', {
      allowSamePageTransition: true,
      transition: "none"
     });`code` Thanks for your help!